# only one statement under if statement being run

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, std

I made a program in C++ that ask for any integer input. The program crashes after only 2 iterations. The code is below:

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{   
    int user_choice;
    std::cout <<"Please enter any number other than five: ";
    std::cin >> user_choice;

    while(user_choice != 5)
    {
        std::cout <<"Please enter any number other than five: ";
        std::cin >> user_choice;
        if(user_choice == 5)
            std::cout << "Program Crash";
            break;
    }
    std::cout << "I told you not to enter 5!";
    return 0;
}
```

I then tried doing this:

```
if(user_choice == 5)
    std::cout << "Program Crash";
    //std::cout << "Shutting Down";
```

Which worked. Why does commenting out the second line, cause the program to run fine?

Comment: `if(condition) { statement1; statement2; }`

Comment: @LogicStuff Could you please explain you comment a bit more

Comment: There's more to your code, like, why are you comparing `user_choice` with `5` literal, when you should do `user_choice == right_answer`? Why do you feel the need to assign `right_answer` to `user_choice` if they're already equal?? You've also hardcoded `5` into the output messages...

Comment: And `I told you not to enter 5!` will always be printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
if (counter == 10)
    std::cout << "Wow you still have not entered 5. You win!";
    user_choice = right_answer;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if (counter == 10)
{
    std::cout << "Wow you still have not entered 5. You win!";
}
user_choice = right_answer;
```

Your problem becomes apparent, `user_choice = right_answer` is not executed only when `counter == 10`. Thus, move it inside the `if () { ... }` block:

```
if (counter == 10)
{
    std::cout << "Wow you still have not entered 5. You win!";
    user_choice = right_answer;
}
```

Comment: @Mr.Python Definitely not, if you haven't already, get a C++ book. You can't jump into C++ and apply constructs from other languages... you get issues like these.

Comment: @Mr.Python I recommend looking up "scope" in there.

Comment: Yes, it's amazing how actually learning the language makes you better at it.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't respect indentation; so when you write:

```
if (counter == 10)
    std::cout << "Wow you still have not entered 5. You win!";
    user_choice = right_answer;
```

the compiler sees:

```
if (counter == 10)
    std::cout << "Wow you still have not entered 5. You win!";
user_choice = right_answer;
```

To put both statements under the `if`, you need braces:

```
if (counter == 10) {
    std::cout << "Wow you still have not entered 5. You win!";
    user_choice = right_answer; 
}
```